# How to replace all group occurrences in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of `\n \n` with `\n\n` (`<new line><space><new line> to <new line><new line>`).

I use this code:

```java
assertThat(
    "\n\n \n \n".replaceAll("(\n \n)+", "\n\n"),
    is("\n\n\n\n")
);
```

But instead of `\n\n\n\n` I get `\n\n\n \n`.

How can I fix regex to get right result?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- *Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.*

Comment: @zlakad that's what OP's using...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I just edited my comment to make a point.

Comment: @zlakad and again, that's what OP's using... OP has a String composed by `\n` characters, and the regex finds those. The issue here is why is not finding the proper pattern and how to replace it several times.

Comment: @zlakad thanks for reply but I don't want to suppress the special meaning of backslash. I have updated my question.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but your regex will match any number of `"\n \n"` consecutive sequences and replace them with a single "`\n\n"`. Might not be what you want. Eg `"\n \n\n \n\n \n"` becomes `"\n\n"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are trying to match a string with overlapping matches, you need to use a [lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(\n (?=\n))+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tozjbc/1)

`(?=\n)` is zero-width assertion that doesn't match just asserts presence of `\n` ahead of current position.